# Can't retrieve the JSON format data from php to android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

It is a register function . I am able to add record to my database. But for the  response made through the php script, I can't show the response or get the response from php to Android.

When the email is duplicated, php should respond with a fail.... how could I get it show on android?

register.php

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';

class User {

private $db;
private $connection;

function __construct() {
    $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
    $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();
}

public function does_user_exist($name,$tel_no,$contact_point,$email,$address,$logo_url, $operation_time,$encrypted_password)
{
    $query = "Select * from shop where email='$email'  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        $json['fail'] = ' Already registered '.$email;
        echo json_encode($json);
        mysqli_close($this -> connection);
    }else{
        $query = "insert into shop (name, tel_no, contact_point, email, address, logo_url, operation_time, password) values ( '$name','$tel_no','$contact_point','$email','$address','$logo_url','$operation_time','$encrypted_password')";
        $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query);
        if($inserted == 1 ){
            $json['success'] = 'Account created';
        }else{
            $json['error'] = 'Wrong password';
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

}

 }


$user = new User();

 ..........
```

Register.java

```
 public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {private EditText nam, teln, 
 contactpoin, emai, addres, logour, operationtim, pw1 , pw2;
private Button btnregister;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static final String Url  = "http://XXXXXX/stampe/register.php";
private StringRequest request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy threadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicy);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();


    nam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    teln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel_no);
    contactpoin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_point);
    emai = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    addres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    logour = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logo_url);
    operationtim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. operation_time);
    pw1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. password);
    pw2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. pwcheck);
    btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(nam.getText().length()==0 ||teln.getText().length()==0 ||contactpoin.getText().length()==0 ||emai.getText().length()==0 ||pw1.getText().length()==0 ||pw2.getText().length()==0   )
            {
                btnregister.setError("請輸入資料!");
            }else if(!pw1.getText().toString().equals(pw2.getText().toString())){
                System.out.println(pw1.getText().toString());
                System.out.println(pw2.getText().toString());
                pw1.setError("兩次輸入的密碼不一致");
            }
            else{

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        System.out.print(jsonObject);
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" +jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){



                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                   HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    hashMap.put("name",nam.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("tel_no",teln.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("contact_point",contactpoin.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("email",emai.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("address",addres.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("logourl",logour.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("operation_time",operationtim.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password",pw1.getText().toString());
                    return hashMap;
                }
            };requestQueue.add(request); }}});}}
```

Comment: Note: Android Studio is the IDE. You’re not trying to get any JSON into it, or to show in it. You’re trying to get it into and Android application. This is an important difference. You wouldn’t say you’re getting data from Notepad if that’s what you write your PHP code on either.

Comment: You see, it's difficult to determine the problem right now because there could be a problem with either your PHP script or Android. Therefore, I would recommend you to test your PHP script via POSTMAN and see if you are getting a valid response (success or failure). If so, please also provide the JSON in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "mydb";

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection Failed" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
else 
    echo "Connection Sucessful"

//$data = $_POST["data"];
$stat = $connection->prepare("SELECT name, tel_no, contact, email, address, 
logo_url ,operation_time, encrypted_password from mytable");

$stat->execute();

$stat ->bind_result($name, $tell_no, $contact, $email, $address, 
$logo_url ,$operation_time, $encrypted_password);

$data = array();

while ($stat->fetch()) {

    $temp = array();
    $temp['name'] = $name;
    $temp['tel_no'] = $tel_no;
    $temp['contact'] = $contact;
    $temp['email'] = $email;
    $temp['address'] = $address;
    $temp['logo_url'] = $logo_url;
    $temp['operation_time'] = $operation_time;
    $temp['encrypted_password'] = $encrypted_password;


    array_push($data, array("data"=>$temp));
}


echo json_encode($data);


?>
```